# External user access

Tags: partner-portal, community-cloud

I have visualforce page created which accessible only if you login to salesforce.

Sales agent fill the form/vf page, when it saved it required customer/contact/account to sign when driver visit them.

Drivers don't have salesforce login.

What is best option to achieve this?

Is Community Cloud is better option or may be some other solution e:g external/partner user access ?

Comment: Using the community cloud or employee cloud would allow you to add users to Salesforce for a lower cost than using full SF licences, You can make the VF page accessible to community users so it could be used from that but the question is really a bit broad to answer at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

[Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) can be used to expose a VF page to "Guest users" (unauthenticated). It comes with some limits like traffic within 24 hours. Best use cases include exposing Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) which you manage as Salesforce Knowledge Base but want to show to wide audience. Or maybe a product catalog (although Commerce Cloud or even SIte.com for beautiful marketing stuff comes to mind).

If you expose your VF page as Site - anybody can find it on the net and interact with it. It becomes your job to protect it somehow (share some secret keyword with drivers?) and if you fail - you can get lots of spam records very fast.

It might be better idea to use some cheap license (but then have Salesforce take care of authenticating the users instead of writing it yourself). Maybe [Chatter Plus](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpHuAAI) license or [Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0) - a lot depends here whether drivers are really your employees or more like partner company. Are you sure that the only thing they'll ever need to access is few VF pages? How many forms need to be signed daily on average?